# What does it mean to store a JWT in memory? And how do I do it?

Tags: javascript, rest, express, jwt, response

I am learing about JWTs and everyone keep telling me "Dont store it in cookies" and "Dont store it in local storage". Ok fine, but then they say "You should store it in memory", and this is where my brain goes pooof.

Lets say I make a fetch request with javascript to my express server, and in the response I get the JWT accessTolken. Now what? How do I store it? And how do I send it along with my next request?

Answer (score -1):

For new JavaScript clients, you should consider not storing the tokens in the browser at all and instead use the BFF pattern as described here in these video:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBFx3MSu1Rc&t=13s